# Python PyAudio installation error in windows i am using python 3.8

Tags: python, pyaudio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIvxE.png)

I am trying to install PyAudio I have downloaded the .whl file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) but its not working is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the cp38.whl not the cp37, also try to run the command in the prompt.